What to do with context in RecyclerView
I tried to create a list of elements using JSON and RecyclerView but I got some errors and I dont know how to fix them
I got this error 'LinearLayoutManager(android.content.Context, int, boolean)' in 'androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager' cannot be applied to '(WeatherActivity.GetUrlData, int, boolean)'
public class WeatherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather);
        int District = getIntent().getIntExtra("District", -1);
        String latitude="";
        String longitude="";
        switch (District) {
            case 0:
                latitude = "55.753600";
                longitude = "37.621184";
                break;
            case 1:
                latitude = "55.838390";
                longitude = "37.525774";
                break;
            case 2:
                latitude = "55.854875";
                longitude = "37.632565";
                break;
            case 3:
                latitude = "55.787715";
                longitude = "37.775631";
                break;
            case 4:
                latitude = "55.692019";
                longitude = "37.754592";
                break;
            case 5:
                latitude = "55.622014";
                longitude = "37.678065";
                break;
            case 6:
                latitude = "55.662735";
                longitude = "37.576187";
            case 7:
                latitude = "55.778003";
                longitude = "37.443533";
                break;
            case 8:
                latitude = "55.829370";
                longitude = "37.451555";
                break;
            case 9:
                latitude = "55.987583";
                longitude = "37.194250";
                break;
            case 10:
                latitude = "55.355802";
                longitude = "37.146999";
                break;
            case 11:
                latitude = "55.594351";
                longitude = "37.371452";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        String url = "https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=" + latitude + "&longitude=" + longitude + "&hourly=temperature_2m,relative_humidity_2m,apparent_temperature,precipitation_probability,snowfall,cloud_cover,wind_speed_10m&wind_speed_unit=ms&timezone=Europe%2FMoscow&forecast_days=1";
        new GetUrlData().execute(url);
    
    
    }
    private class GetUrlData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
    
    
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                URL url1 = new URL(strings[0]);
                connection =(HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
    
                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";
    
                while ((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
                    buffer.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                return buffer.toString();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                if(connection!=null){
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                if(reader!=null){
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(result!=null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray timeArray = object.getJSONObject("hourly").getJSONArray("time");
                    JSONArray temperatureArray = object.getJSONObject("hourly").getJSONArray("temperature_2m");
                    JSONArray humidityArray = object.getJSONObject("hourly").getJSONArray("relative_humidity_2m");
                    JSONArray precipitationArray = object.getJSONObject("hourly").getJSONArray("precipitation_probability");
                    JSONArray cloudArray = object.getJSONObject("hourly").getJSONArray("cloud_cover");
                    JSONArray windSpeedArray = object.getJSONObject("hourly").getJSONArray("wind_speed_10m");
                    JSONArray snowArray = object.getJSONObject("hourly").getJSONArray("snowfall");
                    for (int i = 0; i < timeArray.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            String time = timeArray.getString(i);
                            SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
                            SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
                            Date date = inputFormat.parse(time);
                            String outputString = outputFormat.format(date);
                            String temperature = temperatureArray.getString(i);
                            String humidity = humidityArray.getString(i);
                            double precipitation = precipitationArray.getDouble(i);
                            double cloud = cloudArray.getDouble(i);
                            String windSpeed = windSpeedArray.getString(i);
                            String snowfall = snowArray.getString(i);
                            ArrayList<Condition> conditions = new ArrayList<>();
                            conditions.add(new Condition(outputString, temperature, humidity, precipitation, cloud, windSpeed, snowfall));
                            RecyclerView rcView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView2);
                            WeatherAdapter adapter = new WeatherAdapter(conditions);
                            rcView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                            rcView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
    
                    }
                }
            }
    
    
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

public class Condition {
    private String time;
    private String temperature;
    private String humidity;
    private  double precipitation;
    private double cloud;
    private String windSpeed;
    private String snowfall;

    public Condition(String time, String temperature, String humidity, double precipitation, double cloud, String windSpeed, String snowfall) {
        this.time = time;
        this.temperature = temperature;
        this.humidity = humidity;
        this.precipitation = precipitation;
        this.cloud = cloud;
        this.windSpeed = windSpeed;
        this.snowfall = snowfall;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    public void setTemperature(String temperature) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    public String getHumidity() {
        return humidity;
    }

    public void setHumidity(String humidity) {
        this.humidity = humidity;
    }

    public double getPrecipitation() {
        return precipitation;
    }

    public void setPrecipitation(double precipitation) {
        this.precipitation = precipitation;
    }

    public double getCloud() {
        return cloud;
    }

    public void setCloud(double cloud) {
        this.cloud = cloud;
    }

    public String getWindSpeed() {
        return windSpeed;
    }

    public void setWindSpeed(String windSpeed) {
        this.windSpeed = windSpeed;
    }

    public String getSnowfall() {
        return snowfall;
    }

    public void setSnowfall(String snowfall) {
        this.snowfall = snowfall;
    }
}

public class WeatherAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WeatherAdapter.ViewHolder>{


    private ArrayList<Condition> conditions;

    public WeatherAdapter(ArrayList<Condition> conditions) {
        this.conditions = conditions;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private final TextView dateView;
        private final TextView tempView;
        private final TextView humidView;
        private final TextView precView;
        private final ImageView imaView;
        private final TextView cloudView;
        private final TextView windView;
        ViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            dateView = view.findViewById(R.id.Date);
            tempView = view.findViewById(R.id.Temperature);
            humidView = view.findViewById(R.id.Humidity);
            precView = view.findViewById(R.id.Precipitation);
            imaView = view.findViewById(R.id.WeatherImage);
            cloudView= view.findViewById(R.id.Cloud);
            windView = view.findViewById(R.id.WindSpeed);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public WeatherAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.weather_cardview,parent,false);
        return new WeatherAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WeatherAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Condition condition = conditions.get(position);
        holder.dateView.setText(String.format("%s",condition.getTime()));
        holder.tempView.setText(String.format("Температура воздуха: %s℃",condition.getTemperature()));
        holder.humidView.setText(String.format("Относительная влажность: %s ",condition.getHumidity()));
        holder.precView.setText(String.format("Вероятность осадков: %s процентов",condition.getPrecipitation()));
        holder.cloudView.setText(String.format("Облачность: %s процентов",condition.getCloud()));
        holder.windView.setText(String.format("Скорость ветра: %s м/с",condition.getWindSpeed()));
        if (condition.getPrecipitation()>=50 && condition.getSnowfall().equals("0,00") && condition.getCloud()>=50){
            holder.imaView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rainy);
        }
        else if (condition.getPrecipitation()>=50 && condition.getSnowfall().equals("0,00") && condition.getCloud()<50){
            holder.imaView.setImageResource(R.drawable.rain);
        }
        else if (condition.getPrecipitation()<50 && condition.getSnowfall().equals("0,00") && condition.getCloud()>=50){
            holder.imaView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cloudy);
        }
        else if (condition.getPrecipitation()<50 && condition.getSnowfall().equals("0,00") && condition.getCloud()<50 && condition.getCloud()>10){
            holder.imaView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cloudy_sunny);
        }
        else if (condition.getPrecipitation()<50 && condition.getSnowfall().equals("0,00") && condition.getCloud()<=10){
            holder.imaView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sunny);
        }
        else if (condition.getPrecipitation()>=50 && !condition.getSnowfall().equals("0,00") && condition.getCloud()>=50){
            holder.imaView.setImageResource(R.drawable.snowy);
        }
        else{
            holder.imaView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cloudy_sunny);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return conditions.size();
    }
}


It's because you're using this within the inner class GetUrlData. You actually want the activity context, try using WeatherActivity.this. Although you should probably move your RecyclerView initialisation out of your AsyncTask, and also not use AsyncTask in 2024, but this should at least fix your crash.

Do not use AsyncTask its been deprecated years ago.. And it has lots of issues when it comes to multi threading..

The error occurs because you're using this inside an AsyncTask, which refers to the AsyncTask instance, not the WeatherActivity instance. You need to use WeatherActivity.this to get the correct context.
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    ...
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(WeatherActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    ...
}

While this fixes your current problem, you should be aware that AsyncTask is deprecated and generally not recommended. Check the docs for more info.
